# How to extract elements from a reactive matrix (or data frame) and keep those elements in another reactive expression

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

For example: I already have my_matrix which is just a simple reactive matrix.
I want to extract its rows and assign them to another matrix:

```
R<-as.matrix(NA)   # create an initial matrix to keep results while looping
for (i in 1:10) { R[i]<-(my_matrix()[i,]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is very sparse on details, which makes it hard to provide a good answer. If you follow the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) you should get better answers.

One solution is to create another reactive from the first. For example:

```
new_matrix = reactive({
    original_matrix = my_matrix()
    R = as.matrix(na)
    for(i in 1:10)
        R[I] = original_matrix[i,]
    return(R)
})
```

You can then make use of your new matrix by calling `new_matrix()`, the same way you make use of your original matrix.

Comment: brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. If you find an answer useful it is good practice to up-vote it. If your question has been answered it is good practice to accept a solution.